# How do multiple castings of Demiplane interact with one another?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

So for the spell [Demiplane](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/demiplane), it states:

> Each time you cast this spell, you can create a new demiplane, or have
> the shadowy door connect to a demiplane you created with a previous
> casting of this spell.

Does this mean that you can, for example, create demiplane 1, then on the next casting, create demiplane 2, then demiplane 3, and then on a fourth casting, open demiplane 1 again?

If this is the case, does this mean that you can essentially have as many demiplanes as you want, each for a separate reason?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Yes, you can create an unlimited number.

As you already quoted,

> you can create a new demiplane, or have the shadowy door connect to a demiplane you created with a previous casting of this spell.

It doesn't specify a limit of demiplanes you can have at a time, so you can have an unlimited number of demiplanes, each for their own reason.

Comment: Pretty sure they dissipate if there is nothing contained therein. Also, if they remain permanent there is a chance that others can get to it if they know the make-up of the plane.

Comment: @Slagmoth it doesn't say it dissipates in the spell description, but it would make 'logical' sense, as much as magic ever does, to avoid loads of the things floating around

Answer (score 12):

### You can have multiples, and get to any of them

The line you quote says

> Each time you cast this spell, you can create a new demiplane, or have the shadowy door connect to **a demiplane** you created with a previous casting of this spell.

I have emphasised where it says **a demiplane**. If you could only create one it would say *the demiplane*.